# How to implement the Hough Transform?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, signals, transform

How does one implement a [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) on a text image? I'm looking for pseudo-code (eventually this will be in java).

Here is some background information:

Given an image, determine the equation for a line `y = mx + b`. Typically the Hough Transform is represented in polar co-ordinates such that `Rho = y*sin(theta) + x*cos(theta)`. (I'm not really sure what the `X` and `Y` values correspond to back to the image).

we are only interested in the `Rho` and `theta` values and plot them. The locations with many points in the accumulator (I know some of the implementation, not the execution) is considered a line.

The issue that I don't understand is how to find the `rho` and `theta` that you'd update the accumulator with.

Comment: Let me know if answer was useful! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The simplest case of Hough transform is the linear transform for
>   detecting straight lines. In the image space, the straight line can be
>   described as y = mx + b and can be graphically plotted for each pair
>   of image points (x, y)

So this tells you what `x` and `y` correspond to back in the image.

> In the Hough transform, a main idea is to consider the characteristics
>   of the straight line not as image points (x1, y1), (x2, y2), ..., but
>   instead, in terms of its parameters, such as the slope parameter m and
>   the intercept parameter b.
>
> Based on that fact, the straight line y =
>   mx + b can be represented as a point (b, m) in the parameter space.
>   However, one faces the problem that vertical lines give rise to
>   unbounded values of the parameters m and b. For computational reasons,
>   it is therefore better to use a different pair of parameters, denoted 
>   and  (theta), for the lines in the Hough transform.
>
> The parameter rho represents the distance between the line and the
>   origin, while theta is the angle of the vector from the origin to this
>   closest point.

This tells you what `rho` and `theta` correspond to: they are the representation in polar coordinates of slope and intercept of the line you are trying to describe in your image.

---

On [SourceForge](http://cimg.cvs.sourceforge.net/cimg/CImg/examples/hough_transform.cpp?view=markup) you can find a `C++` implementation of hough transform.

A description from which you should be able to interpret the code which I pointed out in the previous link may be the following:

> The Hough transform algorithm uses an array, called an accumulator, to
>   detect the existence of a line y = mx + b.
>
> For example, the linear Hough transform problem has two unknown
>   parameters: m and b.
>
> For each pixel and its neighborhood, the Hough transform algorithm
>   determines if there is enough evidence of an edge at that pixel. If
>   so, it will calculate the parameters of that line, and then look for
>   the accumulator's bin that the parameters fall into, and increase the
>   value of that bin.
>
> By finding the bins with the highest values, typically by looking for
>   local maxima in the accumulator space, the most likely lines can be
>   extracted